# Kinematics in Induction

Tags: electrostatics

Can neutral object move when it develop opposite polarity during process of induction as electron move in the object from end to another.
If not, then why does small pieces of paper get attracted and move towards scale when we charge  the scale by rubbing it?

Answer (score 0):

Small pieces of paper get attracted to scale because both are different objects and the movement is propelled by the electrostatic force of attraction between scale and paper. Scale is negatively charged and attracts the positive side of the paper so that the paper flies towards scale.

movement occurs in scale because both are independent objects hence intervention of coulomb force induces movement.

In our material if an outside object is helping to induce the material there is some movement but its negligible because the distance is in terms of millions when compared to the atomic scale which is overcome by the normal friction force. In regards to paper the columbic force overcomes papers gravity and friction force (because paper is very light) so paper flies towards scale .In an ideal situation where no gravity or friction present in vacuum the Inducing object's positive charge and negative side's charge of our object's columbic force of  attraction causes it to move towards each other hence net movement is observed

Comment: If this is happening in a vaccum where gravity and friction is absent , when inducing object is inducing electrons in object there is movement observed in the object towards inducing material

Comment: yes but very so slightly @ayu because inducer's positive charge and negative side of our object's columbic force attraction causes it to move

Comment: I have edited my answer to further clarify the point